# Using each/for in Cypress

Tags: javascript, automation, cypress

I have a card with more information that has the next html code. I want each card, except for the first one (so somehow to increase from 1 with the start), to press the "Edit location" button, then to write in the code and other actions for it, and then to move to the next card.

How can I write this in Cypress?

I used this code in Cypress, but no loop is executed, it runs only once on the first card and then stops.

```
cy.get(".card-locations").each(($el, index) => {
  if (index > 0) {
    cy.wrap($el).contains("Edit location").click({ force: true });
    //another code
  }
});
```

HTML code:

```
<div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 card no-select card-locations">

            <!-- card header -->
            

            <div class="card-top-gradient card-top-gradient-noactions animated fadeInDown card-top-gradient-default">

                <!-- card content -->
                <div class="card-content">
                    <div class="card-right-content">
                        <div class="card-name">
                            Location Craiova
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-clinic-name">
                               Bucharest  <br>
                            -- 020202 Romania
                            </div>

                        <ul class="card-details card-details-verbose">

                            <li>
                                <span class="field-name">Timezone</span>
                                <span class="field-value">(UTC+02:00) Athens, Bucharest</span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="field-name">Facility code</span>
                                <span class="field-value">11 Office</span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="field-name">Phone number</span>
                                <span class="field-value"></span>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <span class="field-name">Email address</span>
                                <span class="field-value"><a href="mailto:test@clinic.test">test@clinic.test</a></span>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <!-- card footer -->
            

            <div class="card-footer" style="background-color: #186b65;">
                <div class="button-placeholder">
                    <div class="card-button card-properties footer-left-button">
                        <span data-action="edit" class="edit" entity-detail="editEntity" title="Edit Location" onclick="$.cmtBhv().getJson({ url: '/...' }).toggleEntityDetailsFor({ target: this });">Edit location</span>
                    </div>

                    <div class="card-button card-properties footer-right-button">
                        <span data-action="edit" class="edit" entity-detail="editEntity" onclick="$.cmtBhv().getJson({ url: '/...' }).toggleEntityDetailsFor({ target: this });">Rooms</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

Comment: This problem is not reproducible. Did you leave out something? SO prefers a minimal, reproducible example otherwise the question might be closed.

Comment: The problem as stated is not reproducible, specifically "no loop is executed" does not happen when we try it out (assuming other identical cards are present).

Comment: Why exactly are you checking for **'Edit location'** when it's not on the card?

Comment: It's included in the card, but because it was in the card's footer by mistake, I didn't post it in the code. I've updated it now, it's my fault

Answer (score 2):

Cypress has a `.each()` function that can yield the yielded element, as well as the index (and entire list, if needed). You can easily use this to skip the first card, and continue on. Based on your given HTML, I'm a little confused about which exact elements you want, but based on my best guess (that each `.field-name` is what you want), something like the following could work.

```js
cy.get('.field-name').each(($el, index) => {
  if (index > 0) {
    // code to execute if not the first
  }
});
```

The concept carries over even if I have the elements incorrect -- use `.each()` to yield a list of elements, and use the `index` parameter to exclude the first card.

**Note:** you will have to use `cy.wrap()` to insert the yielded element (`$el` in the above example) back into the Cypress chain.

```js
cy.wrap($el)...
```

Comment: If you want please look at my question, I updated it with the code I wrote. The loop does not work as I wrote, it runs once on the first card (not on the second) and then stops.

Comment: There is only one card in your HTML, so, in this case, it is behaving as expected -- only one card is yielded, so there is only one iteration. What elements are you looking to loop through?

Comment: If I search the console for items with the ".card-locations" class, then I'm shown all the cards I need (except the first one I'd exclude). So in this class I need to operate the rest of the actions. so how do I make iterations for each card, cards that have the same structure as the one shown in the HTML code?

Comment: Given the HTML you posted, I'm not seeing the card having anything containing `Edit Location` -- is there something missing from the HTML? If you added a: cy.log(`Index counter: ${index}`); to the `each()` function before the check for index > 0, do you see the index counter increasing?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize that the code for the card footer was not posted. I have now updated it and you can see the code for "Edit location"